# load huge xml files with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract posts from the stackoverflow data dumps. These are composed of large .xml files, notably a file `Posts.xml` of 90GB.

Unfortunately, the following line uses up to 400GB of RAM, then the usage suddenly decreases to 200GB, but the process seems to hang and never return.

```
with open("Posts.xml", "r") as f:
    posts = BeautifulSoup(f, features="html.parser")  # hangs

for x in posts.findAll("row"):
    if post["posttypeid"] == "1":  # if it's a question
        print(x["body"])
```

I tried different parsers, like `lxml`, but this does not seem to help. Since what I do after this is just enumerate over `posts.findAll("row")` to parse the content of each row, I was wondering whether this is a way to do this without loading the entire file in memory.

Comment: Show us your code (a minimal reproductibe example), what have you tried until now? What is your end goal?

Comment: For such big files, consider using a streaming parser like the `xml.sax` package in the standard library.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire for the sake of simplicity, you can assume I'm just trying to retrieve the content of the posts:
`for x in posts.findAll("row"): print(x["body"])`

Comment: updated the post with a minimal reproductible example. of course that requires to download the 90GB uncompressed dump ^^
`wget https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SAX parser for this, like so:

```py
from xml import sax
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class PostDescriber(ContentHandler):
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'row' and attrs.get('PostTypeId') == '1':
            print(attrs.get('Body'))

sax.parse('Posts.xml', PostDescriber())
```

A SAX parser is a streaming parser; it will call into your handler describing the things it sees (like beginnings and ends of elements) as it parses the file. Since it doesn't have to remember the structure of the file, it doesn't use a lot of memory.

If you want to do something more interesting with the individual question bodies rather than just printing them, those are small enough that you could just pass each to BeautifulSoup in turn.

The `xml.sax` package is part of the Python standard library; it is described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html) and there are [more methods on ContentHandler you can override if needed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects). For XML documents from untrusted sources, the docs recommend the [defusedxml.sax](https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/) package be used instead.